# Gravar arquivo.txt

Tags: java, arquivo, io

Estou com dificuldades em um código que montei. Não consigo encontrar o erro. Meu problema é o seguinte:

Criei um código que gera combinações de números e que deve salvar essas combinações em um arquivo *.txt*. Porém, quando executo o código, ele às vezes salva apenas a última combinação e às vezes não salva nada e às vezes salva algumas combinações, mas não todas que são geradas pelo código. O código que montei chega a gerar mais de um milhão de combinações, será que é por isso que está dando problema?

O código é o seguinte:

```
package gerasorte2;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Combinacoes {

    private int numeros[] = {3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 50, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60};
    private int quantidade = 6;
    private int resultado[] = new int[6];

    public int count = 0;

    public void busca(int inicio, int fim, int profundidade) throws IOException {

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Vander/mega.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        if ((profundidade + 1) >= quantidade) {
            for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {

                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];

                count++;
                System.out.println(resultado[0] + " " + resultado[1] + " " + resultado[2] + " " + resultado[3] + " " + resultado[4] + " " + resultado[5] + "\n");
                bw.write(resultado[0] + " " + resultado[1] + " " + resultado[2] + " " + resultado[3] + " " + resultado[4] + " " + resultado[5] + "\n");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }
        } else {
            for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {

                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];

                busca(x + 1, fim + 1, profundidade + 1);

            }
        }
        bw.close();
        fw.close();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Combinacoes comb = new Combinacoes();

        comb.busca(0, (33 - 6), 0);

        System.out.println("Total de combinacoes: " + comb.count);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu método `busca` é recursivo e ele executa operações de IO. Vamos analisar quais são os problemas com o IO:

1. Cada recursão dele abre um mesmo arquivo, faz nele as operações e fecha. Como o método é recursivo, isso significa que você abre milhões de vezes o mesmo arquivo e fechará ele milhões de vezes também.
2. Para piorar, isso também significa que você abre ele várias vezes e mexe nele enquanto ele já está aberto e sendo escrito de forma independente em outras partes do programa.
3. As diversas escritas que ocorrem de forma independente, sobrescrevem umas as outras, de forma que o conteúdo final do arquivo não será o que você quer. Esse monte de escritas e reescritas ocorrendo simultaneamente gera bastante confusão, pois estas escritas estão competindo umas com as outras de uma forma não-especificada, o que resulta em comportamento indefinido (*undefined behaviour*) e faz com que o resultado no seu arquivo seja tão estranho e não-determinístico.
4. Abrir, escrever e fechar um mesmo arquivo milhões de vezes é uma operação muuuuuuuito lenta de se realizar. Abusar do `bw.flush()` só deixa a situação ainda pior.
5. Acredito que está é uma forma bem curiosa de reduzir a vida útil do seu HD, ao escrever e sobrescrever milhões de vezes o mesmo arquivo repetidamente na mesma posição física do disco em um curto espaço de tempo. Se for feito em um pen-drive, será uma boa forma de danificá-lo de forma permanente, vez que depois de algumas milhares de reescritas, ele se degrada e você começará a ter áreas defeituosas no seu pen-drive.

Além da questão de IO, há outras coisas que podemos notar:

6. `count` é um atributo público. Acredito que você já deve ter lido em um monte de lugares, explicações de porque isso é uma má ideia e uma má prática de programação.
7. O seu algoritmo está fixo para uma `quantidade = 6`. Mudar este valor vai quebrar o algoritmo porque o tamanho do array `resultado` também está fixo em 6 e o `bw.write` escreve exatamente 6 elementos no arquivo.
8. O `(33 - 6)` chapado no código é algo bem chato de se lidar. O nome do arquivo chapado também.
9. A variável `quantidade` pode ser substituída por `resultado.length`.
10. Você está abusando das quebras-de-linhas ao concatenar o `"\n"`. Lembre-se que o `System.out.println` e o `bw.newLine()` já acrescentam as quebras-de-linha. Então a menos que você realmente queira imprimir os números apenas nas linhas ímpares e deixar as linhas pares em branco, esse `\n` é algo que está a mais.
11. É mais legível e recomendável declarar arrays como `int[] nomeDaVariavel` ao invés de `int nomeDaVariavel[]`. O motivo disso é que na primeira forma você tem o tipo da variável completo seguido do nome da variável, que é a forma padrão e que ocorre em todas as outras formas de declarar variáveis no Java. Enquanto que na segunda forma você tem uma parte do tipo da variável, seguida do nome da variável, seguida da outra parte do tipo da variável, o que é confuso, uma vez que a informação sobre o tipo da variável está fragmentada em dois locais distintos.
12. Pra que usar `System.out.println` se você já está salvando tudo em um arquivo? Muita gente não sabe disso, mas o `System.out.println` pode ser uma operação bem lenta e pesada de se usar.

Então, depois de arrumar esses problemas todos listados aí em cima, eis o código resultante aí em baixo (apenas o nome do arquivo era diferente na minha máquina, mas eu coloquei o mesmo nome de arquivo seu no código que se segue):

```
package gerasorte2;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Combinacoes {

    private static final class Buscador implements AutoCloseable {
        private final int[] numeros;
        private final int[] resultado;

        private int count = 0;

        private final FileWriter fw;
        private final BufferedWriter bw;
        private boolean fechado;

        private Buscador(int[] numeros, int quantidade, String arquivo) throws IOException {
            if (arquivo == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("O arquivo não pode ser nulo.");
            if (numeros == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("O conjunto de números não pode ser nulo.");
            if (numeros.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("O conjunto de números não pode ser vazio.");
            if (quantidade <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("A quantidade de números a sortear deve ser maior que zero.");
            if (quantidade > numeros.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Não se pode sortear mais do que todos os números do conjunto.");
            this.resultado = new int[quantidade];
            this.numeros = numeros;
            this.fw = new FileWriter(arquivo);
            this.bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            this.fechado = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            fechado = true;
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        }

        private int busca() throws IOException {
            busca(0, numeros.length - resultado.length, 0);
            return count;
        }

        private String arrayToString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(3 * resultado.length);
            sb.append(resultado[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < resultado.length; i++) {
                sb.append(" ").append(resultado[i]);
            }
            //sb.append("\n");
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private void busca(int inicio, int fim, int profundidade) throws IOException {
            if (fechado) throw new IOException();
            if (profundidade + 1 >= resultado.length) {
                for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {
                    resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
                    count++;
                    String s = arrayToString();
                    //System.out.println(s);
                    bw.write(s);
                    bw.newLine();
                    //bw.flush();
                }
            } else {
                for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {
                    resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
                    busca(x + 1, fim + 1, profundidade + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int busca(int[] numeros, int quantidade, String arquivo) throws IOException {
        try (Buscador comb = new Buscador(numeros, quantidade, arquivo)) {
            return comb.busca();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[] numeros = {3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 50, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60};
        int c = busca(numeros, 6, "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Vander/mega.txt");
        System.out.println("Total de combinações: " + c);
    }
}
```

Testei o código, e funcionou perfeitamente. E foi rápido também:

- Levou apenas 2 segundos para fazer todas as 1.107.568 combinações e salvá-las no arquivo na minha máquina.
- Se você descomentar a linha do `System.out.println`, ele fica bem mais lento, e demora entre 2 minutos e 2 minutos e meio na minha máquina. Entretanto, isso depende muito do tipo de console que está recebendo a saída ou para onde ela é redirecionada (rodei ele por dentro do NetBeans).
- A sua versão original, além de gerar o arquivo de forma errada e abusar do disco rígido, deveria levar provavelmente uns 15 minutos na minha máquina. Não tive paciência ou coragem de executá-la até o fim.

Ah, e se você quiser colocar o `\n` a mais ou insistir em usar o `flush` a cada linha, basta descomentar as linhas deles. Não recomendo e nem vejo necessidade em nenhum dos dois no entanto.